# SQL Query correction required

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mariadb

```
SELECT TOP (2)
    DATEPART(HOUR,t.callerDateTime) as Hour
    ,count(cli) as Count
FROM ivrtimeout t
where convert(date,t.callerDateTime) = convert(date,getdate(),103)
group by DATEPART(HOUR,t.callerDateTime) 
order by DATEPART(HOUR,t.callerDateTime) desc
```

Above Query is working fine in case of Microsoft SQL Server and giving error using in xamp server maria-db.

Can anyone please make correction?

Comment: Add the Error thrown to the question.  `DATEPART()` may need replacement...

Comment: also **TOP (2)** must change to LIMIT 2 at the end of the line

Comment: Do you mean you want a query like this to run on MySQL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  extract(HOUR from callerDateTime) as Hour,
  count(cli) as Count
from ivrtimeout
where callerDateTime >= timestamp(current_date)
group by 1
order by 1 desc
limit 2
```

Comment: Yes! Its working @Bohemian but i need data for current day, its giving only 1 record. I need timeout count counts per hour for whole current day

Comment: @muz try `where callerDateTime >= timestamp(current_date)` instead

Comment: Thnaks Its Working fine